# Is it possible get Telegram member join date of a group?

Tags: python, telethon

Good day,

I am learning how to use python + Telethon to export members from my telegram group.
Below is a portion of the code that exports to csv and it works.
My question is, is it also possible get the join date of my member? Like an extra column called JoinDate

```
with open("members.csv","w",encoding='UTF-8') as f:
writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
writer.writerow(['username','user id', 'access hash','name','group', 'group id'])
for user in all_participants:
    if user.username:
        username= user.username
    else:
        username= ""
    if user.first_name:
        first_name= user.first_name
    else:
        first_name= ""
    if user.last_name:
        last_name= user.last_name
    else:
        last_name= ""
    name= (first_name + ' ' + last_name).strip()
    writer.writerow([username,user.id,user.access_hash,name,target_group.title, target_group.id])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the [GetParticipantRequest](https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.getParticipant). It returns a [participant](https://core.telegram.org/constructor/channelParticipant) which has the field `date` which is claimed to be the "Date joined". I'm not sure, if admin rights are required to see the date, though.